# delphi convert gif to png with transparency

Tags: delphi, png, gif, alpha-transparency

I am trying to convert a gif to png, that's easy, but the problem is the result image is not transparent, also I would like to have in the png image the alpha channel.

This is my code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
png: TPngImage;
 p : TPicture;
begin
 p := TPicture.Create;
 p.LoadFromFile('C:\temp\php.gif');
 png := TPngImage.CreateBlank(COLOR_RGB , 8, p.Width, p.Height);
 png.Canvas.Draw(0,0, p.Graphic);
 png.SaveToFile('C:\Windows\Temp\test.png');
end;
```

The new picture has the background black, should be transparent.

If I try to add the ALPHA in the constructor, is 100% transparent.

```
png := TPngImage.CreateBlank(COLOR_RGBALPHA , 8, p.Width, p.Height);
```

Comment: Try to turn on the `TGraphic` transparency. By default is `false`. `p.Graphic.Transparent := True;`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Max, which Delphi version are you using, I found XE 5  on an older question of you. I could provide a very simple solution without any artefact.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just by drawing GIF image on PNG canvas will not move transparency information from GIF image to PNG.
You will have to do it yourself.

ForceAlphaChannel procedure will create alpha channel for any PNG image based on given TransparentColor.

```
procedure ForceAlphaChannel(Image: TPngImage; BitTransparency: Boolean; TransparentColor: TColor; Amount: Byte);
var
  Temp: TPngImage;
  x, y: Integer;
  Line: VCL.Imaging.PngImage.pByteArray;
  PixColor: TColor;
begin
  Temp := TPngImage.CreateBlank(COLOR_RGBALPHA, 8, Image.Width, Image.Height);
  try
    for y := 0 to Image.Height - 1 do
      begin
        Line := Temp.AlphaScanline[y];
        for x := 0 to Image.Width - 1 do
          begin
            PixColor := Image.Pixels[x, y];
            Temp.Pixels[x, y] := PixColor;
            if BitTransparency and (PixColor = TransparentColor) then Line^[x] := 0
            else Line^[x] := Amount;
          end;
      end;
    Image.Assign(Temp);
  finally
    Temp.Free;
  end;
end;
```

If you add call to ForceAlphaChannel after you have drawn GIF image you will get transparency based on transparent color you define.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
png: TPngImage;
 p : TPicture;
 TransparentColor: TColor;
begin
 p := TPicture.Create;
 p.LoadFromFile('C:\temp\php.gif');
 TransparentColor := clFuchsia;
 png := TPngImage.CreateBlank(COLOR_RGB , 8, p.Width, p.Height);
 // set png background color to same color that will be used for setting transparency
 png.Canvas.Brush.Color := TransparentColor;
 png.Canvas.FillRect(rect(0, 0 , p.Width, p.Height));
 png.Canvas.Draw(0, 0, p.Graphic);
 ForceAlphaChannel(png, true, TransparentColor, 255);
 png.SaveToFile('C:\Windows\Temp\test.png');
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

Since Delphi XE 2 GDI+ is supported, which offers real easy to use options for conversions.
You just need to create TGPImage providing the image file to load and save this image with the wished encoder, found by the desired mime type.

```
uses Winapi.GDIPAPI, Winapi.GDIPOBJ, Winapi.GDIPUTIL;

procedure TForm8.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  encoderClsid: TGUID;
  stat: TStatus;
  IMG: TGPImage;
begin
  IMG := TGPImage.Create('C:\temp\transparent.gif');
  try
    GetEncoderClsid('image/png', encoderClsid);
    stat := IMG.Save('C:\temp\transparent.png', encoderClsid, nil);
  finally
    IMG.Free;
  end;
  if (stat = Ok) then
    Showmessage('Success');
end;
```

examples for the mime types:

```
image/bmp
image/jpeg
image/gif
image/tiff
image/png
```

Answer (score 3):

For older/new Delphi versions (in newer version - change `TPngObject` to `TPngImage`).

If you need to save every frame of (animated) `GIF` into `PNG` (works for non-animated GIFS also):

The first variant code is compatible with the newer [`pngimage`](http://theunknownones.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Libraries/PNGSupport/pngimage.pas) Version 1.56+ (which supports the `CreateBlank` constructor)

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Gif: TGifImage;
  Png: TPngObject; // for new Delphi versions use "TPngImage"
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  TransparentColor, Pixel: TColor;
  I, X, Y: Integer;
  AlphaScanline: pByteArray;
  IsTransparent: Boolean;
  ColorType: Cardinal;
begin
  Gif := TGifImage.Create;
  try
    Gif.LoadFromFile('C:\Downloads\ajax-loader.gif');
    for I := 0 to Gif.Images.Count - 1 do
    begin
      IsTransparent := Gif.Images[I].Transparent;
      TransparentColor := Gif.Images[I].GraphicControlExtension.TransparentColor;
      Bmp := Gif.Images[I].Bitmap;
      if IsTransparent then
        ColorType := COLOR_RGBALPHA
      else
        ColorType := COLOR_RGB;
      Png := TPngObject.CreateBlank(ColorType, 8, Bmp.Width, Bmp.Height); // for new Delphi versions use "TPngImage"
      try
        AlphaScanline := nil;
        for Y := 0 to Bmp.Height - 1 do
        begin
          if IsTransparent then
            AlphaScanline := Png.AlphaScanline[Y];
          for X := 0 to Bmp.Width - 1 do
          begin
            Pixel := Bmp.Canvas.Pixels[X, Y];
            Png.Pixels[X, Y] := Pixel;
            if IsTransparent then
            begin
              if (Pixel = TransparentColor) then
                AlphaScanline^[X] := 0
              else
                AlphaScanline^[X] := 255;
            end;
          end;
        end;
        Png.SaveToFile(Format('%d.png', [I]));
      finally
        Png.Free;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Gif.Free;
  end;
end;
```

For old `pngimage` version before 1.56 which **do not** support `TPngObject.CreateBlank`:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Gif: TGifImage;
  Png: TPngObject; // for new Delphi versions use "TPngImage"
  Bmp: TBitmap;
  TransparentColor, Pixel: TColor;
  I, X, Y: Integer;
  AlphaScanline: pByteArray;
  IsTransparent: Boolean;
begin
  Gif := TGifImage.Create;
  try
    Gif.LoadFromFile('C:\Downloads\ajax-loader.gif');
    for I := 0 to Gif.Images.Count - 1 do
    begin
      IsTransparent := Gif.Images[I].Transparent;
      Png := TPngObject.Create; // for new Delphi versions use "TPngImage"
      try
        if IsTransparent then
        begin
          Bmp := TBitmap.Create;
          Bmp.Assign(Gif.Images[I].Bitmap);
          Bmp.PixelFormat := pf24bit;
          Png.Assign(Bmp);              
          Png.CreateAlpha;
          TransparentColor := Gif.Images[I].GraphicControlExtension.TransparentColor;
          for Y := 0 to Bmp.Height - 1 do
          begin
            AlphaScanline := Png.AlphaScanline[Y];
            for X := 0 to Bmp.Width - 1 do
            begin
              Pixel := Png.Pixels[X, Y];
              if (Pixel = TransparentColor) then
                AlphaScanline^[X] := 0;
            end;
          end;
          Bmp.Free;
        end
        else
          Png.Assign(Gif.Images[I].Bitmap);
        Png.SaveToFile(Format('%d.png', [I]));
      finally
        Png.Free;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    Gif.Free;
  end;
end;
```